# not all trait items implemented, missing: `RemoveItemsLimit`, `AssetIdParameter`, `CreateOrigin`, `CallbackHandle`

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

i gonna add `pallet-assets` in my project but i faced this error :

> error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `RemoveItemsLimit`, `AssetIdParameter`, `CreateOrigin`, `CallbackHandle`
> --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:289:1
> |
> 289 | impl pallet_assets::Config for Runtime {
> | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `RemoveItemsLimit`, `AssetIdParameter`, `CreateOrigin`, `CallbackHandle` in implementation
> |
> = help: implement the missing item: `type RemoveItemsLimit = Type;`
> = help: implement the missing item: `type AssetIdParameter = Type;`
> = help: implement the missing item: `type CreateOrigin = Type;`
> = help: implement the missing item: `type CallbackHandle = Type;`

[Repository](https://github.com/dortajkianoush/substrate_dex)

i did these steps :

1 - Add `pallet-assets` in `Cargo.toml` :

```
pallet-assets = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
```

2 - Add this Config in `runtime.rs` :

```
   pub type AssetBalance = Balance;
pub type AssetId = u32;

impl pallet_assets::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type Balance = AssetBalance;
    type AssetId = AssetId;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type ForceOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type AssetDeposit = ConstU128<1>;
    type AssetAccountDeposit = ConstU128<10>;
    type MetadataDepositBase = ConstU128<1>;
    type MetadataDepositPerByte = ConstU128<1>;
    type ApprovalDeposit = ConstU128<1>;
    type StringLimit = ConstU32<50>;
    type Freezer = ();
    type Extra = ();
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: Can you include the entire error message, if too big, the top most error message?

Comment: @Purple_Turtle questoin is edited , please check the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reading the error, it seems you have incomplete configuration of pallet-assets. Here's what the pallet needs:

```rust
pub trait Config<I: 'static = ()>: Config {
    type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self, I>> + IsType<<Self as Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
    type Balance: Member + Parameter + AtLeast32BitUnsigned + Default + Copy + MaybeSerializeDeserialize + MaxEncodedLen + TypeInfo;
    type RemoveItemsLimit: Get<u32>;
    type AssetId: Member + Parameter + Copy + MaybeSerializeDeserialize + MaxEncodedLen;
    type AssetIdParameter: Parameter + Copy + From<Self::AssetId> + Into<Self::AssetId> + MaxEncodedLen;
    type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>;
    type CreateOrigin: EnsureOriginWithArg<Self::RuntimeOrigin, Self::AssetId, Success = Self::AccountId>;
    type ForceOrigin: EnsureOrigin<Self::RuntimeOrigin>;
    type AssetDeposit: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
    type AssetAccountDeposit: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
    type MetadataDepositBase: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
    type MetadataDepositPerByte: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
    type ApprovalDeposit: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
    type StringLimit: Get<u32>;
    type Freezer: FrozenBalance<Self::AssetId, Self::AccountId, Self::Balance>;
    type Extra: Member + Parameter + Default + MaxEncodedLen;
    type CallbackHandle: AssetsCallback<Self::AssetId, Self::AccountId>;
    type WeightInfo: WeightInfo;
    type BenchmarkHelper: BenchmarkHelper<Self::AssetIdParameter>;
}
```

However, that said, if you switch your pallet-assets to use `polkadot-v0.9.32`, you don't need to provide the extra configuration and this should work with it.

Answer (score 1):

This error means there are some trait items not implemented. The pallet_assets::Config is the trait being implemented on the runtime type. For example something like this

````
trait Foo {
    fn foo();
}

struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {}
// error: not all trait items implemented, missing: `foo`
```
````

as you can see when implementing the trait for the struct it doesn't contain the trait item`fn foo()`. The solution would be to add `fn foo()` like

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo();
}

struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn foo() {} // ok!
}
```

So in your case the trait items not implemented are included in the error and the solution would be to add `type RemoveItemsLimit = ();`, `type AssetIdParameter = ();`, `type CreateOrigin = ();`, `type CallbackHandle = ();` to your trait implementation like:

```
 pub type AssetBalance = Balance;
pub type AssetId = u32;

impl pallet_assets::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type Balance = AssetBalance;
    type RemoveItemsLimit = ();
    type AssetId = AssetId;
    type AssetIdParameter = ();
    type Currency = Balances;
    type CreateOrigin = ();
    type ForceOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type AssetDeposit = ConstU128<1>;
    type AssetAccountDeposit = ConstU128<10>;
    type MetadataDepositBase = ConstU128<1>;
    type MetadataDepositPerByte = ConstU128<1>;
    type ApprovalDeposit = ConstU128<1>;
    type StringLimit = ConstU32<50>;
    type Freezer = ();
    type Extra = ();
    type CallbackHandle = ();
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```